# Empty space at the bottom of the website & invisible menu in windowed mode

Tags: html, css

I've encountered errors in my code, it's css related and only happens when I put my browser in windowed mode. I get a perhaps 50-100px high white space at the bottom of the site. As well as my css menu disappears when in windowed mode after becoming smaller than a bit over half of my screen.

I've looked through recent articles for a solution, and have changed the "footer/footerbg, body & pagewrap" divs and I've had no luck, mainly changed the parameters "bottom, margin-bottom".

Same for the menu, I've tried assigning a width to the "cssmenu" and positioned it as absolute to stop it from disappearing but couldn't find a solution.

Could anyone hep me out?

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/1zn82kqr/`
```

This is how it looks for me in windowed mode.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkC9b.jpg

Comment: Here's the fullscreen one http://imgur.com/F3erxMJ

Comment: It's tricky without code. Please provide your HTML and CSS Code.